# Scala - Overriding trait method using a sub context bound method

Tags: scala, traits, context-bound

For

```
sealed trait User {...}
sealed trait Trader extends User {...}

trait AuthObject

trait AuthUserObject {
  def authorize[U <: User](u: U): Boolean
}

trait AuthTraderObject extends AuthUserObject {
  def authorize[T <: Trader](t: T): Boolean
}

object HasPaidTax extends AuthTraderObject {
  def authorize[T <: Trader](t: T): Boolean = t.hasPaidTax
}
```

This doesnt build. Error:

> Error:(15, 7) overriding method authorize in trait AuthUserObject of type     [U <: users.User](u: U)Boolean;
>   method authorize has incompatible type
>    def authorize[T <: Trader](t: T): Boolean
>         ^

I need to restrict `AuthTraderObject` to `Trader` user since only trader pays tax. Please, how is this override possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should understand the reason for the error: since `HasPaidTax` extends `AuthUserObject`, you can ascribe this type to it:

```
val auth: AuthUserObject = HasPaidTax
```

But for any `auth: AuthUserObject` and `user: User`, you can call `auth.authorize(user)`. So when overriding methods, you can't narrow the argument types or type bounds.

For the solution, you can go with pamu's answer or just move the type parameter to the type (should be equivalent for this case):

```
trait AuthUserObject[U <: User] {
    def authorize(u: U): Boolean
}

trait AuthTraderObject[T <: Trader] extends AuthUserObject[T] {
    def authorize(t: T): Boolean
}

object HasPaidTax extends AuthTraderObject[Trader] {
    def authorize(t: Trader): Boolean = t.hasPaidTax
}
```

Answer (score 4):

User type and then override type when necessory

```
trait User

trait Trader extends User


trait AuthUserObject {
  type U <: User
  def authorize(u: U): Boolean
}

trait AuthTraderObject extends AuthUserObject {
  override type U <: Trader
  override def authorize(u: U): Boolean
}
```

Comment: Using `type U <: User` will represent it as `AuthUserObject.this.U`. Will work alright in explicit cases. But doesnt work with abstract methods of an abstract class or trait upper type bounded `trait Authorizer[U <: User]`